# Combine the modules "Field Multiple Limit" and "Grid Field Formatter"

Tags: drupal-7

I made a Drupal 7 site and I want to limit the number of pictures (multi-value field is a teaser view.)
I want 1 row of 5 thumbnail images.
When I use the Field Multiple Limit to limit the number of images to 5 and use the Grid Field Formatter module to display them in a grid, the result is strange.

[image link](http://www.lmtc.be/een.png) (my reputation is less then 10, I cannot include images, Sorry.)

The number of displayed images is limited to 5, but it's followed by empty table cells (one of each image).

[image link](http://www.lmtc.be/twee.png)

I tried to solve it by changing the weight of the modules, therefore I installed Grid Field Formatter.

[image link](http://www.lmtc.be/drie.png)

I moved the Field Multiple Limit in front of the Grid Field Formatter module, but nothing changed. The empty cells with css makeup remain visible.
How do I solve this?

Kind greetings,

Comment: Can you provide the relevant portions of your code?

Comment: It's not code related, I added links to images. My Reputation is less then 10, so I can't include images.